# Check element viewport visibility in levels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if a dom-elment is visible in the viewport in different "visibility levels". I know how to check if it's visible or not, but this time i need an indicator of how visible the element is. Think of it as 3 colors: Green, Yellow and Red. Where green is 100% visible and red is not visible at all.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to write jQuery or Javascript for this?

Edit: 0 to 100 would also be a great indicator. 0 is 0 % visible and 100 is 100% visible.

Comment: please post a code of what you've tried so far. Also why don't you use the alpha channel of `rgba` or the CSS property `opacity`?

Comment: I haven't tested anything yet, cause I don't know where to start. It's not about opacity, it's about an elements visibility. Let's say you have a huge paragraph of text and on a mobile device you can only see 50% of it in the viewport.

Comment: then your question is really confusing. You can start with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately for you, I had to develop *almost* what you want. It's a jQuery extension that tells you how visible an element is relative to the browser window. It returns an object with two properties, horizontal and vertical. If vertical value is -1, then the element is invisible and over the viewport. If it is 0, then it's visible. If the result if 1, then invisible but under the viewport. Similarly for *horizontal*.

The difference is that '0' doesn't differentiate between 'completely in the viewport' or partially in the viewport. I needed it to determinate if something was above, in, or below the viewport (and the same for left and right). However, it's a good point to start and it can easily be changed to what you need.

```
    jQuery.fn.viewportPosition = function () {
        var $window = $(window);
        var position = this.offset();
        var viewport = { bottom: $window.height(), right: $window.width() };
        var rect = { top: position.top, left: position.left, bottom: position.top + this.height(), right: position.left + this.width() };
        return {
            vertical: (rect.bottom < 0) ? -1 : (rect.top > viewport.bottom) ? 1 : 0,
            horizontal: (rect.left < 0) ? -1 : (rect.left > viewport.right) ? 1 : 0
        };
    };
```